# implement rel="next rel="prev"

Tags: magento-1.9, seo, pagination

i know that question have been asked here before but i have no solution.
im trying to implement pagination rel="next" and rel="prev" and after a lot of research i found this code:

```
<?php
$actionName = $this->getAction()->getFullActionName();
if ($actionName == 'catalog_category_view') // Category Page
{
$category = Mage::registry('current_category');
$prodCol = $category->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', array('in' => array(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG, Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)));
$tool = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html_pager')->setLimit($this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list_toolbar')->getLimit())->setCollection($prodCol);
$linkPrev = false;
$linkNext = false;
  if ($tool->getCollection()->getSelectCountSql()) {
     if ($tool->getLastPageNum() > 1) {
        if (!$tool->isFirstPage()) {
            $linkPrev = true;
            if ($tool->getCurrentPage() == 2) {
                $url = explode('?', $tool->getPreviousPageUrl());
                $prevUrl = @$url[0];
            }
            else {
                $prevUrl = $tool->getPreviousPageUrl();
            }
        }
        if (!$tool->isLastPage()) {
            $linkNext = true;
            $nextUrl = $tool->getNextPageUrl();
        }
    }
}
if ($linkPrev) echo '<link rel="prev" href="' . $prevUrl . '" />';
if ($linkNext) echo '<link rel="next" href="' . $nextUrl . '" />';
}
?>
```

i added this code to my `head.phtml` and it dosent show in the page source as rel="next" and rel="prev".

please help me with this.

Comment: on which page you are checking this code?

Comment: this one: https://www.shakedbeauty.com/cosmetics/holy-land.html

Answer (score 0):

Your code might not get full Action name, that's why its not going in to `IF` condition.

Try this code:

```
$actionName = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction()->getFullActionName();
```

Comment: i tried this but still not working.

Comment: what you are getting in that variable?

Comment: please can you help?